# Why does c_str() print the string twice?

Tags: c++, c-strings

So...
when I go:

```
cout<<stringName<<endl;
```

I get:

```
NT
```

But when I go:

```
cout<<stringName.c_str()<<endl;
```

I get:

```
NTNT
```

Why?

Comment: Are you using wstring by any chance.

Comment: Don't even know what that is.

Comment: Are you doing any fork()ing in the vicinity -- maybe you have multiple processes flushing the more-or-less same buffers.

Comment: There is some other error in your code.

Comment: @windfinder, please report back.  What did it turn out to be?  Have you tracked down the bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick test with the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string str = "NT";
    cout << str.c_str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

produces one instance of NT so it looks like you probably have another output call somewhere.

Comment: How could that be the cause?  Assuming he has changed just this one line from 'stringName' to 'stringName.c_str()', that can't change the number of times the string is printed.  Plus, he prints a newline, so it's clearly not two instances of this code being run.

Comment: @Larry There is no indication of what the rest of the code looks like or that the same input was used between runs so it could be in a conditional somewhere. There is also no guarantee that a previous call would include an endl either. I said 'probably' for a reason.

Comment: @Kevin If there is "another output call" it happens first and doesn't have a newline. I was taking at face value that the only thing he changed was that one line, not the "other". Either way, the CHANGE in behavior as described is not accounted for merely by presence of another "NT" print command.

Comment: @Larry I agree with you that taking this at face value possible hints at a more difficult to diagnose problem, but my first instinct in a situation like this is to look for the simplest most obvious solution first; especially when given limited details and no context.

Answer (score 4):

A traditional C string (accessed through a `char const*`) has a sequence of characters terminated by a character 0.  (Not the numeral `0`, but an actual zero value, which we write as `'\0'`.)  There's no explicit length — so various string operations just read one character at a time until it hits the `'\0'`.

A C++ `std::string` has an explicit length in its structure.

Is it possible that the memory layout of your string's characters looks like this:

```
'NTNT\0'
```

but the string's length is set to 2?

That would result in exactly this behavior — manipulating the `std::string` directly will act like it's just two characters long, but if you do traditional C operations using `s.c_str()`, it will look like `"NTNT"`.

I'm not sure what shenanigans would get you into this state, but it would certainly match the symptoms.

One way you could get into this state would be to actually *write* to the string's characters, something like: `strcat((char *)s.c_str(), "NT")`

Comment: You would get that behaviour only if std::string::c_str() is faulty. c_str() is guaranteed by the standard (21.3.6[1]) to point to an array (not necessarily the same storage as string uses internally) terminated by a \0

Comment: @Steve, not if c_str() doesn't do anything and the data is already maintained in a null terminated way. Then if you overwrite that null terminator by directly manipulating it with data(), it could have this result.

Comment: And in general, if you've done anything invalid to the string object and the result is that c_str() doesn't do what you expect, that doesn't mean c_str() is faulty ;-)

Comment: A C-string is not a `char*`. A C-string is a `char[N]`, possibly `const`, and you generally pass around pointers to it.

Comment: -1: This answer can be summed up as "You're getting "NTNT". It is possible that something went wrong, such that you're getting "NTNT". That would match the symptoms."

Answer (score 2):

Show more code. It seems like you did `cout << ealier` and forgot that you did it. What does it print if you do  `cout<< "mofo" << stringName.c_str()<< "|||" << endl;` Does it say `NTmofoNT|||` ? if so that may well be what happened ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with `c_str()`, but probably related to some other anomaly in the rest of the program.

Make a "hello world" application that does these same operations and you'll see it works fine there.